# WPF DataTemplate Textblock binding for SelecteItem of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my Employee and Company class

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public Employee() 
    {
    }

    public Employee(int id, string name, string address)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Address = address;
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public Employee SelectedEmployee { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {
        this.Name = "Test Technologies";
        this.Employees = new List<Employee>();

        this.Employees.Add(new Employee(1, "Prabodha", "Kottawa"));
        this.Employees.Add(new Employee(2, "Prasad", "Rukmalgama"));
        this.Employees.Add(new Employee(3, "Nisitha", "Nugegoda"));
        this.Employees.Add(new Employee(4, "Danesh", "Kesbawa"));
        this.Employees.Add(new Employee(5, "Jeewan", "Pannipitiya"));

        this.SelectedEmployee = this.Employees.First();
    }
}
```

And I have a DataTemplate called EmployeeCompanyDetails

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<DataTemplate x:Key="EmployeeCompanyDetails">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="Azure">
            <TextBlock Text="~~ Employee Details ~~" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtSelectedDetails" Text="{Binding View.CurrentCell.Item.ID, ElementName=DataGrid}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And here is my MainWindow.xaml file

```
<Window x:Class="DataTemplateTEst.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataTemplateTEst">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:Company/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/DataTemplateTEst;component/DataTemplates/EmployeeDetails.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedEmployee.Name}"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeCompanyDetails}"/>
</Grid>
```

What I want is I want to show the name of the selected Employee in the txtSelectedDetails(TextBlock in the DataTemplate). Since following code segment is wrong this is not working.

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="txtSelectedDetails" Text="{Binding View.CurrentCell.Item.ID, ElementName=DataGrid}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
```

Comment: Why are you binding to the grid's current cell id? You can just `{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myGrid}`

Comment: Here is my sample code https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74394917/DataTemplateTEst.rar

Comment: I am not downloading your code, this can be easily resolved here. Did you try what I suggested? Did you understand it?

Comment: I just added that Text="{Binding View.CurrentCell.Item.ID, ElementName=DataGrid}" code for test purpose.What I want is to show the selected row ID, Name or Address on that TextBlock (txtSelectedDetails). As my knowledge I have to set the correct property path for the text. I have set that property path to "View.CurrentCell.Item.ID" and I think this property path is wrong.

Comment: @Hondaputha if you want to show multiple information in a TextBlock you'll have either to: Override ToString to show what you want or make a converter with the selecteditem as ConverterParameter. About the binding, just name your DataGrid and then use {Binding ElementName=TheNameOfYourDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem}

Comment: Dude I don't know what language you speak, but `"I have set the correct property path...I think this property path is wrong"` is very confusing in any language. Glad to be of service!